# Bootstrap color span formatting

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to place a span / like full color container. If I place span in html then all of them have the same height? What is the easiest way how to place spans with a different height?

Comment: Could you please show us some working HTML code with span elements? Then we can discuss it and ask you questions about it to find out what you really want.

Answer (score -1):

HAy you cant give a `span` a height, but you can set the `span` in a `div`. The div get the height porperty.

```
 <div style="height: xxxpx">
    <span>Your text</span>
    </div>
```